# How can i show 24 hrs format in vf page?

Tags: visualforce, datetime

I get 05:50 pm but it should be 17:50

```
<apex:outputText value=" {0,date,dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}">
        <apex:param value="{!wrap.lastmodifyDate}"/>
</apex:outputText>
```

Comment: are you looking for something like this:                                 <apex:outputText value="The formatted time right now is: 
 {0,date,yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss z}">
 <apex:param value="{!NOW()}" />
</apex:outputText>

Comment: Are you sure you are already using 24 hrs format `HH:mm`.

Comment: here you can see nice explanation where all those symbols are coming from and how to display era -- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html